# How to remove + in array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Return value success but include "+"

```
var dataKeterangan = $("#KETERANGAN").val();
//From here
    var dataDetail = $("#DETAIL").val();
    var dataRekomendasi = $("#REKOMENDASI").val();
    var dataVona = $("#VONA").val();
    var dataLevel = $("#LEVEL").val();

$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        url: '<?php echo base_url('Lap_geologi/updateDraft'); ?>',
        data : {
            dataKeterangan : dataKeterangan,
            dataDetail : dataDetail,
            dataRekomendasi : dataRekomendasi,
            dataVona : dataVona,
            dataLevel : dataLevel
        },
```

```
Array ( 
[dataKeterangan] => Dari kemarin hingga pagi ini visual Gunungapi terlihat jelas hingga tertutup kabut. Teramati asap kawah berwarna putih dengan intensitas tebal, tinggi sekitar 200 meter dari puncak. Melalui rekaman seismograf pada 24 April 2019 tercatat: - 2 kali gempa Hembusan - 1 kali gempa Tektonik Jauh 
[dataDetail] => DETAIL=VONA+terkirim+kode+warna+ORANGE,+terbit+tanggal+21+April+2019+pukul+21:41+WITA,+terkait penurunan+intensitas+erupsi+pasca+erupsi+pukul+18:56+WITA+dengan+tinggi+kolom+abu+±+3.000 m+di+atas+puncak.+Kolom+abu+teramati+berwarna+kelabu+dengan+intensitas+tebal+condong+ke arah+barat. )
```

how to remove "+" in my data can someone help me?

Comment: you can do `str_replace()`

Comment: Those `+` can only be there if you have code that explicitly adds them. It'd make more sense to find such code and get rid of it, rather that letting it corrupt your data to fix it again later.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes I will try to fix it thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply `foreach()` and `str_replace()`

```
foreach($array as &$value){
  $value = str_replace('+',' ',$value);
}
```

Sample output:-https://3v4l.org/l1Evd

Comment: Thx bruh,for now it seems like this is the best answer because there are no strings containing other +

Comment: @RagilPratama  glad to help you :):)